# calculate floats with bash

Tags: linux, bash

What is the most elegant way to make this work?

```
prc_count=$(nproc --all)
factor=0.5
prc_count=$((prc_count*factor))
```

I tried with awk/echo and no success

Comment: If you're just multiplying by a constant factor like `0.5`, you could do `$(( a * 5 / 10 ))`. Also, if you're going to say "I tried xyz and no success", it's better to show what exactly you tried and what exactly the problem was, it makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks, the idea that factor can be modified from 0.5 to 2.5 or 3